# Custom config with service/di references

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection

For my project I want to specify some custom configuration. I have a bunch of 'mappers' that have some properties and will refer to other services.

For example, I would like my config to look like this:

```
self_service:
  mappers:
    branche_vertalingen:
      data_collector: "@self_service.branche_vertalingen.data_collector"
      data_loader: "@self_service.branche_vertalingen.data_loader"
      map_data: SelfServiceBundle\Entity\BrancheVertalingMapData
```

Where `self_service` is the bundle name, `mappers` is the 'container' where all the mappers are defined. And `branche_vertalingen` is one of the defined mappers, there can (and will) be many more. At the moment, each mapper has a `data_collector` and a `data_loader` that refer to services defined in the bundle's `services.yml`, and a `map_data` property which refers to an entity's class name.

I have put this configuration in `SelfServiceBundle/Resources/config/config.yml` and import it in `app/config/config.yml`.
I have create a `SelfServiceExtension` class according to [this article](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/extension.html). In the extension's `load()` method I receive my defined configuration as an array. So far, so good.

The problem I am having is that the value for `data_collector` I receive is just the defined string, and not the service I was expecting. No problem, I thought. I have a `$container` available, I will just look it up, but I can't get the service there.

**The question: How do I make sure I can get the service I reference in the config?**

---

I had already tried doing the same in a `parameters` block so that I wouldn't even need a bundle Extension, but doing that I got this error: `You cannot dump a container with parameters that contain references to other services`. So after that I tried to do it via an Extension.

Comment: Have you considered [tagged services](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/tags.html) as an alternative solution? Seems a lot simpler.

Comment: Yes I have, but I don't think it solves my problem. I guess I could add a datacollector tag and a dataloader tag. And add a 'mapper_name' tag or something like that to map it back to 'branche_vertalingen'. But how would I configure the 'map_data' element? And besides that, I think it would be advantageous to have a central configuration that ties it all together. Having said all that, could you maybe expand your suggestion into an answer? Maybe i'm making this a bigger deal than it should be.

Comment: Maybe I'm making it too simple.. ;) But currently I'm thinking about some reusable service class/interface that accepts the required data (`data_collector`, `data_loader`, `map_data`) as constructor arguments. Then one central service wich will be configured during a compiler pass that would collect all tagged services and making them available to your application. With this, the tag could be as simple as: `- tag { name: mapper, branch: branche_vertalingen }` Would this be viable?

Comment: I have never used a compiler pass before, have not yet needed it and could not really comprehend the documentation. This is what I have implemented at the moment. As was my first thought, I put all the config in the parameters under a `mapper` umbrella. I inject this into a service, along with the `service_container` so I can get get the necessary references and make them available where I need them. It is not very bad, but I don't like that I need to inject the `service_container`. I will take another look at your compiler pass option.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have enough time now to add an example as an answer, but if you don't have one by tomorrow, I'll try to add one.

Comment: can you include your `SelfServiceExtension` file pls? and which other file in your dependencyInjection namespace :)

Comment: You definitely need a compiler pass.  In your pass you would actually define your branche_vertalingen service.  I don't think tags are necessary here.  Check the docs and maybe the framework bundle for examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I wrote in the comments, I think tagged services are a good fit for this. It allows you to very easily add or remove mappers just by tagging a service. This way there's no hard requirement for all mappers to *live* at the same place or similar.

Using interfaces to ensure that everything is *wired* correctly also allows for easy extension.

To see how this can even incorporate your initial idea, see the example at the end of this answer.

---

### usage

```
/** @var $mapperManager MapperManager */
$mapperManager = $this->get('app.mapper_manager');

dump($mapperManager);
foreach ($mapperManager->getMappers('branche_vertalingen') as $mapper) {
    dump($mapper);
}
```

---

### implementation

(closely following the [official docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/tags.html)):

**service.yml**

```
services:
    app.mapper_manager:
        class: AppBundle\Mapper\Manager

    # mappers

    app.mapper_1:
        public: false
        class: AppBundle\Mapper\DefaultMapper
        arguments:
            - "a"
            - "b"
            - SelfServiceBundle\Entity\BrancheVertalingMapData
        tags:
            - { name: app.mapper, branch: branche_vertalingen }

    app.mapper_2:
        public: false
        class: AppBundle\Mapper\DefaultMapper
        arguments:
            - "c"
            - "d"
            - SelfServiceBundle\Entity\BrancheVertalingMapData
        tags:
            - { name: app.mapper, branch: branche_vertalingen }

    app.mapper_3:
        public: false
        class: AppBundle\Mapper\DefaultMapper
        arguments:
            - "e"
            - "f"
            - SelfServiceBundle\Entity\BrancheVertalingMapData
        tags:
            - { name: app.mapper, branch: other_branch }
```

**the compiler pass**:

```
<?php
// src/AppBundle/DependencyInjection/Compiler/MapperCompilerPass.php
namespace AppBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Reference;

class MapperCompilerPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        if (!$container->has('app.mapper_manager')) {
            return;
        }

        $definition = $container->findDefinition('app.mapper_manager');
        $taggedServices = $container->findTaggedServiceIds('app.mapper');

        foreach ($taggedServices as $id => $tags) {
            foreach ($tags as $attributes) {
                $definition->addMethodCall('addMapper', [$attributes['branch'], new Reference($id)]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**using the compiler pass**:

```
<?php
// src/AppBundle/AppBundle.php
namespace AppBundle;

use AppBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler\MapperCompilerPass;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;

class AppBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $container->addCompilerPass(new MapperCompilerPass());
    }
}
```

**a simple manager class** (call it whatever fits better):

```
<?php
// src/AppBundle/Mapper/Manager.php
namespace AppBundle\Mapper;


class Manager
{
    private $mappers = [];

    public function addMapper($branch, MapperInterface $mapper)
    {
        if (!array_key_exists($branch, $this->mappers)) {
            $this->mappers[$branch] = [];
        }

        $this->mappers[$branch][] = $mapper;
    }

    public function getMappers($branch)
    {
        if (!array_key_exists($branch, $this->mappers)) {
            // handle invalid access
            // throw new \InvalidArgumentException('%message%');
        }

        return $this->mappers[$branch];
    }
}
```

**a default mapper class** (this is actually not required, but could make things easier to start with):

```
<?php
// src/AppBundle/Mapper/DefaultMapper.php
namespace AppBundle\Mapper;


class DefaultMapper implements MapperInterface
{
    private $dataCollector;
    private $dataLoader;
    private $mapData;

    public function __construct($dataCollector, $dataLoader, $mapData)
    {
        $this->dataCollector = $dataCollector;
        $this->dataLoader = $dataLoader;
        $this->mapData = $mapData;
    }

    public function getDataCollector()
    {
        return $this->dataCollector;
    }

    public function getDataLoader()
    {
        return $this->dataLoader;
    }

    public function getMapData()
    {
        return $this->mapData;
    }
}
```

**and finaly a simple interface to use with the data mappers**:

```
<?php
// src/AppBundle/Mapper/MapperInterface.php
namespace AppBundle\Mapper;


interface MapperInterface
{
    public function getDataCollector();
    public function getDataLoader();
    public function getMapData();
}
```

---

### a little *extra*

With an additional compiler pass (or only, see code-comments) you could also extend the above solution:

**using an extra compiler pass, like**:

```
<?php
// src/AppBundle/DependencyInjection/Compiler/MapperCollectionCompilerPass.php
namespace AppBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler;

use AppBundle\Mapper\DefaultMapper;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Definition;


class MapperCollectionCompilerPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    private $parameterName;

    public function __construct($parameterName)
    {
        $this->parameterName = $parameterName;
    }

    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        if (!$container->has('app.mapper_manager')) {
            return;
        }

        if (!$container->hasParameter($this->parameterName)) {
            return;
        }

        $definition = $container->findDefinition('app.mapper_manager');
        $mappers = $container->getParameter($this->parameterName);

        foreach ($mappers as $branch => $meta) {
            $mapper = new Definition(DefaultMapper::class, [
                new Reference($meta['data_collector']),
                new Reference($meta['data_loader']),
                $meta['map_data'],
            ]);

            $mapper
                ->setPublic(false)
                ->addTag('app.mapper', ['branch' => $branch])
            ;

            $container->addDefinitions([$mapper]);

            // If you don't want to use tags, simply add the 'addMethodCall'
            // from MapperCompilerPass here
            // $definition->addMethodCall('addMapper', [$branch, $mapper]);
        }
    }
}
```

**adding it to the bundle**:

```
<?php
// src/AppBundle/AppBundle.php
namespace AppBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use AppBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler\MapperCompilerPass;
use AppBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler\MapperCollectionCompilerPass;


class AppBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $container->addCompilerPass(new MapperCollectionCompilerPass('mappers'));
        $container->addCompilerPass(new MapperCompilerPass());
    }
}
```

**and adding the config**:

```
# app/config/services.yml
parameters:
    mappers:
        branche_vertalingen:
            # !note the missing @
            data_collector: app.some_service
            data_loader: app.some_service
            map_data: SelfServiceBundle\Entity\BrancheVertalingMapData
```

Comment: Hmm.. somehow the comment I posted yesterday is gone... Anyway, thanks for the thorough answer! I like your first solution better. That way my editor gives me code completion, while it won't in your second example. I have just implemented it without a hitch, works like a charm! Cheers